# PHP var_dump array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

```
array(14) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "myUserName"
  ["UserID"]=>
  string(7) "myUserName"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "myPassword"
  ["passwordID"]=>
  string(10) "myPassword"
  [3]=>
  string(24) "myEmail@domain.com"
  ["emailAddress"]=>
  string(24) "myEmail@domain.com"
  [4]=>
  string(7) "myFirstName"
  ["firstName"]=>
  string(7) "myFirstName"
  [5]=>
  string(8) "myLastName"
  ["lastName"]=>
  string(8) "myLastName"
  [6]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["active"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

how do i access the contents of this array using PHP?

the above was a var_dump($info)

Comment: I suggest you read the manual page for arrays in PHP as a start.

http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 7):

It depends on which part of the array you are trying to access.

If you are trying to access a specific item, you can access it by its index ; for instance :

```
echo $info['passwordID'];
```

Should give you :

```
myPassword
```

*(edit after the comment)*

For the email address, there is this portion in your `var_dump`'s output :

```
["emailAddress"]=>
  string(24) "myEmail@domain.com"
```

This indicates that the e-mail address is stored in the array as an element that has the key "`emailAddress`".

Which means you should be able to get that e-mail address like this :

```
echo $info['emailAddress'];
```

And as you also have this portion of text in the `var_dump`'s output :

*(About that duplication of data, you should read [Pekka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314054/php-var-dump-array/2314074#2314074), who provides an idea of why your data is in your array twice, with both integers and strings as keys)*

```
[3]=>
  string(24) "myEmail@domain.com"
```

You could also use :

```
echo $info[3];
```

*(of course, in each of those cases, you could also store this to a variable for futures re-use)*

Another solution, if you want to access each item, would be to use some [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop ; for instance :

```
foreach ($info as $key => value) {
    echo "Value for key $key is $value <br />";
}
```

You might want to go through the [arrays section of the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), for more informations.

And, also, the section about [array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php).

Comment: I'm trying to get the email address and I cant get it to print

Comment: Using Martin's approach, you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: @orange : I've edited my answer ; and as I said during my edit, you should also read Pekka's answer, who explains *"why"* you're probably getting this kind of data.

Comment: +1 once again, the most detailed answer in da house! :) If that doesn't help the OP, nothing will.

Comment: I know this is almost a decade old, but it's got a typo. Change from `foreach ($info as $key => value) ` to `foreach ($info as $key => $value) `. You forgot the $ from the value and without it it returns: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '['`

Answer (score 3):

You can use either the numeric or the associative key:

```
echo $array[0]; // outputs 1
echo $array["id"];  // outputs 1
```

I'm guessing this is the result of a `mysql_fetch_array()` operation, isn't it? You may want to specify whether you want a numeric or associative array using [**the second parameter to that function**](https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array).

Example:

```
$record = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC);  // for associative keys only
$record = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_NUM);    // for numeric keys only
```

Comment: +1 : I've edited my answer to put a link to yours ; nice catch, about the `mysql_fetch_array` stuff !

Answer (score 0):

The array appears to have both string and numeric keys.  You can access the fields using the array index operator `[]`.  Supply either the numeric key or the column name:

```
echo $info['UserID']; // output "myUserName"
echo $info['emailAddress']; // output "myEmail@domain.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

if `$info` is the array, then you can `echo $info[6]` for example.
If you want it as a string then `$s=print_r($info,true);`

It seems you are doing some thing wrong, as there shouldn't be a need to access array like that, and there other ways to access objects as arrays.